# VBA Loop through dynamic array to locate matching dates and return matched date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set that will be dynamic and constantly changing in size. The end goal is to return or print out a yyyy-mm from the current year if there is a matching yyyy-mm from the prior year in the data set. These dates are also specific to a specific shop that the user has selected previously. It would return a max of 12 months. This would then be used for a data validation list for a user to select those specific time frames. My current code is as follows.

```
Public Sub Date_Data_Validation_List()

    Dim Jan As Date, Feb As Date, Mar As Date, Apr As Date, May As Date, Jun As Date, Jul As Date, Aug As Date, Sep As Date, Oct As Date, Nov As Date, Dec As Date
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Shop As String
    
    Let Shop = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("main").Range("B2")

    Set rng = Range("D:D")

    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dv_test").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      
    For i = 1 To LastRow

        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dv_test").Range("A" & i).Value = Shop Then
            'j = j + 1
            Dim iVal As Integer
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("dv_test").Range("C" & i).Value = "01" Then
                iVal = iVal + 1
            '    Let Jan = Cells("B", i)
            End If
        End If
     Next i
End Sub
```

Right now the code accounts for the matching time frames but I am specifying a value and would rather VBA find the matches itself.

Comment: I think it would help if you could upload a sample of your inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: The user selects a 3 digit code for a shop name that is in data validation list; AAE, 055, TEL. Things like that. Based off their selection in that cell I am looking for VBA to look through the dynamic array of data that can change every week and see if there is a 2019-10 date and a 2020-10 date or any year really so as to future proof the sheet. The data will only ever be pulled a year in the past. I then need VBA to return the 2020-10 date if there is a 2019-10 to compare it to. October is just an example. I would need it to return all 12 months if there is 12 months to compare.